# How find difference of two text files in s3 using lambda services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have to compare two files in aws s3 bucket and generate a new file with only the difference.

I have tried to do using Java, NodeJs and Python, but i couldn't find way to do that.For example we have some libraries in nodejs and python, but it requires input as 'path', but when you retrieve from s3 bucket its coming in different format.

Comment: What do you mean by different format ? the url is different ?

Comment: Thank Nirojan for the response. what i meant was if some function expecting 'file path' as parameter, what could be the corresponding value we can pass since we are accessing from s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Your AWS Lambda function could:

- Download the two files to `/tmp/`
- Use the [difflib — Helpers for computing deltas](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/difflib.html#module-difflib) module to find differences
- Save the results to a file in `/tmp/`
- Upload the results file to Amazon S3
- Delete temporary files that were generated (in case the container is reused, since there is a 500MB limit in `/tmp/`)

Comment: Thanks John for the response.I don't have any prior programming experience in Python. I was looking for some running samples that could be used directly. However i found a way to do that using java.